# What does “X-MC-User” mean in the email header?

Tags: email, headers

I received this email from a MailChimp campaign and would like to know the meaning of "X-MC-User". Is it the owner of the account that is sending me the email? The specific header entry is:

```
X-MC-User: cfb37e41050726c424019265b
```

Here is the full header for review:

```
Subject:
From: ...
Reply-To:
To:
Date:
Message-ID: <tl71.mcdlv.net>
X-Mailer: MailChimp Mailer - CIDc40ee845e433f8bc0c14
X-Campaign: mailchimpcfb37e41050726c424019265b.c40ee845e4
X-campaignid: mailchimpcfb37e41050726c424019265b.c40ee845e4
X-Report-Abuse: Please report abuse for this campaign here:
http://www.mailchimp.com/abuse/abuse.phtml?
u=cfb37e41050726c424019265b&id=c40ee845e4&e=33f8bc0c14
X-MC-User: cfb37e41050726c424019265b
Feedback-ID: 96911361:96911361.93855:us18:mc
List-ID: cfb37e41050726c424019265bmc list
X-Accounttype: pd
X-Original-Sender: ...
List-Unsubscribe: https://...-manage.com/unsubscribe?u=cfb37e41050726c424019265b&id=3a3b197724&e=33f8bc0c14&c=c40ee845e4>, 
33f8bc0c14@mailin.mcsv.net?subject=unsubscribe>
List-Unsubscribe-Post: List-Unsubscribe=One-Click
Sender:
x-mcda: FALSE
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="_----------
=_MCPart_1132754214"
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Internet packet headers (including email and HTTP requests headers) that are prefixed with `X-` indicate that they are non-standard; they are made up by a particular piece of email software (or perhaps by a user).

Making an inference from the rest of the headers, `X-MC-User` refers to the MailChimp user that sent you that email as part of a campaign.